# Puntual and uniform convergence of a sequence of functions in $L\subseteq [0,1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $f_{n}(x)=x^{n}(1-x^{n})$ and let $x\in[0,1]$. I have to determine the set of puntual convergence $L\subseteq[0,1]$ and the limit function $f:L\subseteq [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I also have to determine the uniform convergence of $f_{n}(x)$ in $L\subseteq [0,1]$ and in every interval of the form $[0,M]$ where $0<M<1$. I considered the important limit: $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}y^{n}=\begin{cases}+\infty 
\,\,y>1\\ 1\,\,y=1\\ 0\,\,-1<y<1\\ \nexists\,\,y\le -1 \end{cases}\\$ to study the puntual convergence, but got that $f(x)=0$ in $L=[0,1]$. It seems to be a mistake in my opinion. Also, setting up the limit: $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}$ sup$_{[0,1]}$$|x^{n}(1-x^{n})-0|$ it is $0$ after the derivative tells that $f_n'(x)=nx^{(n-1)}=0\iff x=0$ so I have uniform convergence in $L=[0,1]$ and I can cut the other part of the exercise. Where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true that $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}$ sup$_{[0,1]}$$|x^{n}(1-x^{n})-0|=0$. In fact, $sup_{[0,1]}|x^{n}(1-x^{n})-0|\geq  (1-\frac 1 n)^{n}(1-(1-\frac 1 n)^{n}) \to e^{-1}(1-e^{-1})>0$.
Hence, we don't have uniform convergence on $[0,1]$

Comment: So, I don't have uniform convergence on $L=[0,1]$ and have to study the uniform convergence on the intervals of the form $[0,M]$ where $0<M<1$. That makes sense. But at this point is it true $L=[0,1]$ or I made a mistake earlier ?

Comment: You computed the derivative of the wrong function. How did you compute the supremum over $[0,1]$? What I have shown is that we don't have uniform convergence on $[0,1]$. @mc271_

Comment: Yes, I understand now that we do not have uniform convergence on $[0,1]$ by your proof. I computed the derivative of $f_{n}(x)=x^{n}(1-x^{n})$ to find the maximum and I found $f_{n}'(x)=nx^{(n-1)}$. Should I compute the derivative of what function to find the maximum over $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: $f_n(x)=x^{n}-x^{2n}$ so $f_n'(x)=nx^{n-1}-2nx^{2n-1}$. @mc271_